# Placeholder image the size of the image area?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, background, placeholder

What is the best approach to creating a loading image to take the place of a .gif while it loads? I want to have a placeholder image about 325x325 (the size of the gif) to hold content in place.

I have unsuccessfully tried background: url() and have not looked into JS/jQuery, as I'm not very versed in it.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you post your code so far?

Comment: When you say background:url() didn't work what did it do? Have you set the container element for the background to display:block (or similar) and set a width and height on it? it may be working but be 0px x 0px

Comment: There isn't much relevant code. It's a single picture with an id of "eye" centered on a page. When I set to background:url() with an image of equal size, the image would just disappear when the link was unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

If you can or want to use jQuery, you can just use the `onLoad` function to load the image and do something after it's loaded (like replace the loading gif with the image).

Checkout [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6n6LC/3/). It lets you show an image which loads immediately, as well as an image that takes 1000ms to load.

How is this done? Take a look at this code:

```
var url="http://i.imgur.com/QoRjjFu.jpg", //the URL of the image to load
    image=$("#some-image"),               //get the image element           
    newImage = new Image();               //create a new image 

//this is called after the image loads
newImage.onload = function(){
    image.attr('src', url).show();  //swap out the loading gif
};

//this triggers loading the image, which will trigger onload above when done
newImage.src = url;
```

Now, if the image loads quickly, you don't want to quickly flash the loading gif and then switch the new image in (because it causes a flickering effect). You want to skip the loading gif all together and just show the image. You can do this by using a timeout and only showing the loading gif if the new image hasn't loaded in, say, 200ms:

```
var url="http://i.imgur.com/QoRjjFu.jpg",
    image=$("#some-image"),
    newImage = new Image();

newImage.onload = function(){
    clearTimeout(loadingGif); //clear the loading gif timeout
    image.attr('src', url).show();
};

//if the image hasn't loaded after 200ms, show the loading gif
var loadingGif = setTimeout(function(){
   image.show();
}, 200);

newImage.src = url;
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: I have no reason to believe this doesn't work but I can't seem to get the image to switch, despite copying the script exactly and changing the id to some-image. Any idea what could cause it?

Comment: Did you try the JSFiddle? You're going to need to attach it to an event, even if that event is just the onload event of the page.

Comment: And how would I do that? Thanks in advance

Comment: Wrap it inside of `$(function{ ... });`